# “additional properties not defined” error in API call of Survey Monkey

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I'm trying to use the create [question](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%7Bsurvey_id%7D/pages/%7Bpage_id%7D/questions?api_key=apikeyhere) endpoint of the Survey Monkey API. It is sending back following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
    "message": "additional properties not defined by 'properties' are not allowed in field '_data'",
    "id": "1002",
    "name": "Bad Request",
    "http_status_code": 400
  }
}
```

I'm able to do successfully use all other API endpoints and have a valid API key and OAuth token.

Here's an example JSON body that I'm sending to: [https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/pages/{page_id}/questions?api_key=apikeyhere](https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/%7Bsurvey_id%7D/pages/%7Bpage_id%7D/questions?api_key=apikeyhere)

```
{
  "headings": [
        {
          "heading": "A question about primates",
          "random_assignment": {
            "percent": 50,
            "position": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "heading": "A question about primates phrased slightly differently.",
          "random_assignment": {
            "percent": 50,
            "position": 2
          }
        }
    ],
  "family": "open_ended",
  "subtype": "single",
  "position": 1,
  "sorting": {
    "type": "textasc",
    "ignore_last": true
  },
  "required": {
    "text": "This question is required!",
    "type": "at_least",
    "amount": "1"
  },
  "validation": {
    "type": "integer",
    "text": "Validation has failed!",
    "min": 20,
    "max": 30
  },
  "forced_ranking": true
}
```

Any idea what might be causing the error? It seems like all fields are correctly named and where they're supposed to be, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The field `forced_ranking` is not allowed for family=open_ended.

The example in the documentation at  https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-pages-id-questions is incorrect, we'll fix it.

Also, `sorting` is not available for open_ended questions as there is no choices to have shown sorted.

Also for `required` only validation type `all` seems to work. So the following payload should work:

```
{
  "headings": [
        {
          "heading": "A question about primates",
          "random_assignment": {
            "percent": 50,
            "position": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "heading": "A question about primates phrased slightly differently.",
          "random_assignment": {
            "percent": 50,
            "position": 2
          }
        }
    ],
  "family": "open_ended",
  "subtype": "single",
  "position": 1,
  "required": {
    "text": "This question is required!",
    "type": "all",
    "amount": "0"
  },
  "validation": {
    "type": "integer",
    "text": "Validation has failed!",
    "min": 20,
    "max": 30
  }
}
```

We'll fix the documentation to make it more clear. You can see formats for specific question types here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#formatting-question-types

Comment: I tried with the new request that you had provided but now it is giving new error as:

{  "error": {
    "docs": "https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes",
    "message": "Oh bananas!  We couldn't process your request.",
    "id": "1050",
    "name": "Internal Server Error",
    "http_status_code": 500
  }
}

Comment: It works with only one item in headings list. When more than one heading list item is present than it gives the above error. The new request which works with only one heading list is as below: 

`{"headings":[{"heading":"A question about education","random_assignment":{"percent":50}}],"family":"open_ended","subtype":‌​"single","position":1,"required":{"text":"This question is required!","type":"all","amount":"0"},"validation":{"type":"integer","text":"Val‌​idation has failed!","min":20,"max":30}}`

Comment: I just tested the same request and it created fine. What plan do you have with SurveyMonkey? Perhaps there is a plan specific issue as I believe multiple headings is for Gold plans and above, so if you're below that you should get a 40* error code. If you're still getting the 500 contact support with your API key so we can track down in the logs and fix it.

Comment: I am using Basic Free plan and getting status 500 error message as mentioned in my above comments. Will drop a mail about the same to SurveyMonkey support team. Thanks @akand074